# How to reuse Db Connections in Nodejs and Express

Tags: node.js, express, couchbase

I am wondering what the best way is to reuse db connections in my case its couchebase connection in NodeJs as well as express.
For the Express part i created a middleware like this

```
var couchbase = require('couchbase')
var config = require('../config/config')

module.exports = (req,res,next)=>{
  var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster(config.cluster)
  cluster.authenticate(config.userid, config.password)
  let bucket = cluster.openBucket(config.bucket);
  bucket.manager().createPrimaryIndex(function() {});
  req.bucket = bucket;
  req.N1qlQuery = couchbase.N1qlQuery;
  next();
}
```

which works fine in the express app since i tell it to

```
const dbSessionMiddleware = require('../middleware/couch')
app.use(dbSessionMiddleware)
```

which allows me to access it via req.bucket . My issue is that i have controllers in my app which in case might call a helper function and they might call another function to get some data back. I want to avoid to have to keep passing the request object down 5 levels or so to use the middleware. Is there a better way how i can expose the connection / bucket to normal functions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried taking your init code out of the middleware function? The [Couchbase Documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/nodejs-sdk/2.6/start-using-sdk.html) doesn't show it being used that way. Albeit the example is in vanilla Node. By placing it in a middleware function, you're going to be re-connecting to your database everytime the server receives a request.

I connect to my Mongo server in top-level app.js body, which allows the connection to persist. Then I can just import the mongoose reference I need in my Models and Controller to outline how to fetch certain data, and then call the controller's method inside the relevant route endpoint.

*Edited to show an example of assigning bucket as a controller class field*

**In your app.js**

```
const couchbase = require("couchbase");
const config = require("../config/config");

// ...app.js

const CouchController = require("../controllers/CouchController")(couchbase, config);

// app.js...
```

**In your controller**

```
class CouchController {

  constructor(couchbase, config) {
    // You may either pass couchbase and config as params, or import directly into the controller
    this.cluster = new couchbase.Cluster(config.cluster);
    this.cluster.authenticate(config.userid, config.password);
    this.bucket = cluster.openBucket(config.bucket);
    this.N1qlQuery = couchbase.N1qlQuery;
  }

  doSomeQuery(queryString, callback) {

    // Use your query however its meant to be used. I'm not familiar with couchbase queries.
    this.bucket.manager().createPrimaryIndex(function() {

      this.bucket.query(
        this.N1qlQuery.fromString("SELECT * FROM bucketname WHERE $1 in interests LIMIT 1"),
        [queryString],
        callback(err, result)
      )

    });
  }

}
```

**Then call your Controller method from inside a route**

```
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {

  let searchParam = req.query.someParam;

  CouchController.doSomeQuery(searchParam)
    .then(result => {
      res.json(result);
    });

});
```

Comment: I get the controller / route part as i use it already. What i am not clear on is how do i access the defined bucket from controller as i need the bucket to make the actual call

Comment: You could assign the bucket variable as a field in the controllers constructor. Then you would import the controller into your app.js and instantiate it with all of your other init code. To give the constructor a reference to your couch base connection you could either do that in the constructor as well, or initialize it in app.js and pass it to the constructor as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a specialized module (e.g. `db.js`) where you would implement a singleton for you pool of connections.

```
// pseudo-code
export const getDb = () => {
  let db

  if (!db) {
    const connection = createConnectionPool()
    db = connection.db
  }

  return db
}
```

This function could be imported on your middleware and on other parts of your code.